# Sequence with uncomputable limit

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

Is it possible to give an example of a sequence that satisfies the following criteria

1. Strictly positive entries
2. Monotone increasing
3. Bounded above by 1

whose limit is uncomputable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enumerate all Turing machines as $(T_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ and let $$h(n)=\begin{cases}1&\text{if $T_n$ halts with empty input}\\ 0&\text{if $T_n$ does not halt with empty input}\end{cases},$$ now we can code the halting problem into a single real number $r=0.h(1)h(2)h(3)\ldots$, which is obviously not computable, so we only need to come up with an increasing sequence whose limit is $r$, but this is easy, by letting $a_n$ be the first $n$ digits of $r$. If you want a strictly increasing sequence you can simply pass to a subsequence of the $a_n$.